# get nav menu to go to the bottom of my header

Tags: html, css

I have a header with a logo and a nav menu.

I want the nav menu to align on the bottom of the logo by the red bottom border.

Here is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/nnEr9/3/

The nav bar should aligned to the far right, with the logo on the far left.

The width should be 960px.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/nnEr9/4/

Comment: Put the navbar in a `<div>` and float it to the left, so that it's aligned with the logo. Edit: Ok, so you want it to the right edge of the logo?

Comment: @WojtekT no because, I want the nav menu on the right not under the logo

Comment: Give #header a width, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kjmatthews/nnEr9/5/

Comment: Have you tried padding the navbar to the `left`?

Comment: @Kyle that seems to be the same js fiddle as mine

Comment: You're right - I forgot to update! Link is fixed now in above comment.

Comment: @Kyle i need the width to be `960px` and doesnt work when you set it to that width

Comment: Then set a `margin-right:` on #mainNav instead. It should be somewhere around `70px` because your logo is about `590px` wide, but you may want to fiddle with that to make it look like you want it to. http://jsfiddle.net/kjmatthews/nnEr9/7/

Comment: Use positioning instead of floats: http://jsfiddle.net/LSz3m/. But I think I misunderstood your question...

Comment: @Zeta thats right. you should make that an answer

Comment: @Zeta, you appear to be the only one who _did_ understand! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use positioning instead of floats. Add `position:relative` to your `#header` and `position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;` to your navigation.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LSz3m)

See also:

- W3C: [CSS2.1: 9.8.2 Relative positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#comp-relpos)
- W3C: [CSS2.1: 9.8.4 Absolute positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#comp-abspos)

Answer (score 0):

is that the result you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/nnEr9/3/